# Disabling the Required *Title Field

Tags: title

Still pretty new to EE.  Running EE 2.9.2

I have tried a couple of third_party downloads but to no avail:

- SP Title Filler
- MX Title Control

How can I disable the required title field entirely?  It keeps popping up as a required field.  I understand it is required for editing the entry (having a link to click on).  But can I generate this title based on some other channel fields included in the channel group?

Comment: Is that not what MX title control does? Setup the config and off you go or  I missing something? Works with Channel form to.

Comment: MX Title Control doesn't seem to work.  I would like the title to be automated with the following three channel fields: "{vehicle_year} {vehicle_make} {vehicle_model}"

Comment: What exactly happens? Last MX Title Control should work just fine with EE2.9.2.   Any JS errors on page? Is title field hidden? Do you use it for channel form or CP Publish page?

Comment: The title field is not hidden.  I can get it into another tab, but not remove it altogether. When I enter in the values for the following three fields 1. {vehicle_year} 2. {vehicle_make} 3. {vehicle_model} and click Submit it returns back with "*Title field is required".  It doesn't pre-populate the title field based on those three values I have entered.

Answer (score 1):

According to the blurb for [MX Title](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-title-control) it can combine a combination of elements to achieve that:

*For patterns you can used any of exist EE2 tags (category, **all custom fields,** plug-ins etc.) successfully tested with EE 2.9.2*

You will have to then require all your custom fields but it should work. What did you actually try?